# How can I change a property type with maker-bundle on symfony

Tags: php, database, symfony

I created a table with a PRICE property but I made it to be an Integer and I would want to change it to a FLOAT type.

The problem is that I made a migration and now the problem is also on database so I cannot change simply the PHP code I think.

Comment: My recommendation would be to change the type in your class, make the migration and then run it against a copy of your database. You could also run a query to see if any data would be lost in the conversion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can change property type in your entity class (also in getter & setter )
And make a :

" symfony console doctrine:schema:update -F " to update your database.